# How to inherit static xml in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

When I edit an email in the Email Marketing App I have the option to double-click on a button and a Link-Dialog opens where I can modify the URL, size, style, and color of the button:

[Default Link-Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYcce.png)

Well, I'm now trying to add a text on top.

To do this I found the original XML which is located here:

"addons/web_editor/static/src/xml/wysiwyg.xml"

and this is the code I'm trying to inherit:

```
<!-- Link Dialog (allows to choose a style and content for a link on the page) -->
<div t-name="wysiwyg.widgets.link" class="o_link_dialog">
    <div class="row">
    <form class="col-lg-8">
        <div t-attf-class="form-group row#{widget.needLabel ? '' : ' d-none'}">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3" for="o_link_dialog_label_input">Link Label</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="label" class="form-control" id="o_link_dialog_label_input" required="required" t-att-value="widget.data.text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row o_url_input">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3" for="o_link_dialog_url_input">URL or Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" id="o_link_dialog_url_input" required="required"/>
                <div class="form-check o_strip_domain d-none">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="o_link_dialog_url_strip_domain" checked="checked" class="form-check-input"/>
                    <label for="o_link_dialog_url_strip_domain" class="form-check-label font-weight-normal">
                        Autoconvert to relative link
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3">Size</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select name="link_style_size" class="form-control link-style">
                    <option value="sm">Small</option>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Medium</option>
                    <option value="lg">Large</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3">Style</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select name="link_style_shape" class="form-control link-style">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Default</option>
                    <option value="outline">Outline</option>
                    <option value="rounded-circle">Rounded</option>
                    <option value="outline,rounded-circle">Outline-Rounded</option>
                    <option value="flat">Flat</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-md-3">Color</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="o_link_dialog_color">
                    <label role="button" t-attf-class="o_link_dialog_color_item o_btn_preview btn btn-link text-center" data-color="">
                        <span>L</span>
                        <input class="d-none link-style" name="link_style_color" type="radio" value=""/>
                        <i class="fa"/>
                    </label>
                    <t t-foreach="['first', 'second', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger']" t-as="color">
                        <label role="button" t-attf-class="o_link_dialog_color_item o_btn_preview btn btn-#{color}" t-attf-aria-label="Color for #{color}" t-attf-title="Color for #{color}">
                            <input type="radio" name="link_style_color" class="d-none link-style" t-att-value="color"/>
                            <i class="fa"/>
                        </label>
                    </t>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-9">
                <label class="o_switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_new_window" t-att-checked="widget.data.isNewWindow ? 'checked' : undefined"/>
                    <span/>
                    Open in new window
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-lg-4 o_link_dialog_preview">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <label>Preview</label>
            <div style="overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px;">
                <a href="#" id="link-preview" aria-label="Preview" title="Preview"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I created a new file in my module with the same name and directory:

"static/src/xml/wysiwyg.xml"

And I tried two ways to inherit this XML and add a text but they don't seem to work at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <div t-inherit="web_editor.wysiwyg.widgets.link" t-inherit-mode="primary">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='row']" position="before">
            <h2>This is a test!</h2>
        </xpath>
    </div>

    <div t-extend="wysiwyg.widgets.link">
        <t t-jquery="div.row" t-operation="before">
            <h2>This is a test!</h2>
        </t>
    </div>
 </template>
```

All I want is something like this:

[Custom Link-Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANHY7.png)

NOTE: I also added the XML file in the MANIFEST like this:

'qweb':             ['static/src/xml/wysiwyg.xml'],

Does anyone know how to inherit a static XML file properly?

Comment: Which Odoo version?

Comment: @Kenly I'm using Odoo 13.0 Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

Keep the second example, replace `div` with `t` and `template` with `templates`

You can locate the first child to add the text like in the image

***Example:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="wysiwyg.widgets.link">
        <t t-jquery="div:first-child.row" t-operation="before">
            <h2>This is a test!</h2>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```